# Calculating upper and lower confidence limits on a population estimate derived from multiple point estimates

Tags: confidence-interval, predictive-models

I am generating a river reach population estimate for a freshwater mussel by summing point estimates made across a gridded point network (within the reach) using a generalized linear mixed model framework. I have generated 95% confidence/prediction intervals at each of the ~150,000 point locations in R. I have summed all of the point estimates to derive the reach population estimate, but am unsure how to derive a single confidence interval for the population estimate using the 150,000 individual-point confidence intervals.  My question: Is it statistically valid to simply sum all the lower estimates and upper estimates to obtain the absolute upper and lower most population confidence limits?

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understood the question, but it doesn't sound like it.